# Regex pattern to match states

Tags: regex

I need to match only the city and state names from the pattern below. Example: I want to extract only Sacramento, California, Vancouver, British Columbia. I do not want USA and CANADA.

I wrote the following reggex [A-Z][a-z]+ but it matches states with a space in their name as multiple matches and not a single match.

`~ Sacramento, California ~ USA;~ Vancouver, British Columbia ~ CANADA`

or

`~ Belgaum, Karnataka ~ INDIA;~ Mumbai, Maharashtra ~ INDIA;~ Raipur, Chhattisgarh ~ INDIA;~, Goa ~ INDIA;~, Uttar Pradesh ~ INDIA;~,~ CHINA ~ Turan, North District ~ ISRAEL`

Comment: ~ Belgaum, Karnataka ~ INDIA;~ Mumbai, Maharashtra ~ INDIA;~ Raipur, Chhattisgarh ~ INDIA;~, Goa ~ INDIA;~, Uttar Pradesh ~ INDIA;~,~ CHINA
~ Turan, North District ~ ISRAEL

Comment: I have to match the city and state names in this data set and not the countries. Countries are in UPPER CASE

Comment: It only works for the Sacramento and Vancouver record

Comment: Try [`[A-Z][a-z]+(?: +[A-Z][a-z]+)*`](https://regex101.com/r/oK5vB2/5) then.

Comment: Are you using it in R?

Comment: R code: `regmatches(x, gregexpr('[A-Z][a-z]+(?: +[A-Z][a-z]+)*', x))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have only ASCII letters in your input, you can use

```
[A-Z][a-z]+(?: +[A-Z][a-z]+)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK5vB2/5)

**Pattern details**:

- `[A-Z][a-z]+`  - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with 1+ lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?: +[A-Z][a-z]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `+` - 1 or more spaces
  - `[A-Z][a-z]+`  - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with 1+ lowercase ASCII letters